# How to add new fields to a VF page when they are not included in the custom controller used for the page

Tags: visualforce, controller, controller-extension, custom-controller, extension

I have a custom controller and VF page which allow my users to create and save a contract by using several information fields on the opportunity and related account page. Since this was first created, new fields were added to the opportunity page. I would like to add a few of them to the VF page but I can't because they are not included in the original controller. How can I achieve this? Do I need to change the whole controller? (The horror) 
...or can I just write an extension with the fields that I need to add and put it in the VF page?
Thank you so much for any help

Comment: do you have any standard controller of this ?

Comment: The standard controller for this would be the opportunity controller but it is not included in the VF page. I have thought of using the Opportunity standard controller as an extension on the VF but was afraid that might clash with the logic used in the custom controller. Should/can I use the standard controller as an extension to the custom one?

Comment: update this question with your vf page and apex class. let us see your current implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not currently using a standard controller you **may** have to update your Controller to be able to do so.

If you do not see a line in your controller like:

```
public YOURCONTROLLERNAME (ApexPages.standardController ...){...}
```

Then you will have to add that to use a standard controller.
You cannot use a standard controller to a page as an extension, rather it is the other way around. You would do this:

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="YOUR PREVIOUS CONTROLLER NAMES"/>
```

You will have to move the code from the original instantiation method to the new one with the standardController or simply use `this()` as the code body in the standardController instantiation.

Adding a standard controller should not mess with your current functionality as extension methods are always checked first before standardController methods. (i.e. a save method will override the standardController save method).

Then you can add fields to the VF page that are not in the SOQL **as long** as your page is launched with an ***id*** parameter

Answer (score 0):

Ok I see that it is going to be slightly more difficult than anticipated. Can i just write a controller to exclusively add the fields that I need and use it as an extension for my VF page? Something like this:

```
public class extensiontocontract {
    public String jobId {get;set;}
    public Opportunity opp {get;set;}
    public extensiontocontract(){
      jobId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('jobId');
      opp = [SELECT Account.ShippingStreet,Account.ShippingCity,Account.ShippingState,Account.ShippingPostalCode,
          Property__r.ShippingStreet,Property__r.ShippingCity,Property__r.ShippingState,Property__r.ShippingPostalCode
           FROM Opportunity WHERE Id =: jobId];

    }
}
```

Comment: this is not an answer and should be added back into the original post